# Building a set of time-dependent ensemble models: Can I stack different models at each time step?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, stacking

I am trying to predict the values of a physical quantity $A(t)$ at different time steps $t$ using Machine learning. The thing is that, because my training data are time dependent, I have to make a different regression model for each time step $t$. For making these models, I stack each time two CART and two Linear models, however I have noticed from the CV results that for some $t$ one or more of these four models may totally fail.

Hence my question is the following: Can I, depending on the CV scores, stack for each $t$ a different combination of CART and linear models or this will cause artifacts in my predicted time series?

Thank you!